# Browser sync, gulp, mongodb and express server

Tags: express, gulp, browser-sync, nodemon

Trying to put together a project running an express server and gulp, browsersync, nodemon and mongodb. However I seem to be an Error: listen EADDRINUSE when I add browsersync. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This means you already have a program listening on the port you are trying to use. What port are you running your application on? Is it 3000? If so, stop all other programs you have running that are using that port and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes I stopped all other programs - I think something was wrong with the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining in the browser-sync configuration the port to use?
In that case, the port needs to be something different from the one (if any) defined from the proxy. This works in my setup:

```
    gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
      browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3000",
        browser: ['google chrome'],
        port: 4000
      });
    });
```

As reference, the full gulpfile.js (that uses nodemon and browsersync) is [here](https://github.com/gvaldambrini/madam/blob/489fd3559906f0a56998d4a35835af8fafed4407/gulpfile.js).

Comment: yes I have that assigned - I ended up using livereload and it works pretty nicely. When I had a very basic server file nodemon and browser-sync worked ok, but when I added my mongodb and passport config it had the same error